# Calling another ajax function in $.ajax.done(). Return is empty?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to perform an ajax call after the 1st ajax call is done.

**js:**

```
function addMessage(message) {
    var func = 'addMessage';
    var args = [message];
    var formData = {'action': func, 'args': args };

    var ajaxRequest =
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../inc/ajax.php',
        data: formData
      });

      ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 
        getMessageNew(data);
      })

}

function getMessageNew(insertid) {
    var func = 'getMessageNew';
    var args = [insertid];
    var formData = {'action': func, 'args': args };

    var ajaxRequest =
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../inc/ajax.php',
        data: formData
      });

      ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 
          console.log(data);
        })

}
```

the php function `addMessage` returns a plain integer which is the last insert id from MySql.

**php:**

```
function addMessage($message) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_message (message_body) VALUES (?)';
    $args = array($message);
    return pdoInsert($sql, $args);
}
function getMessageNew($insertid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT message_body FROM tbl_message WHERE m.id = ?';
    $args = array($insertid);
    return pdoSelect($sql, $args); }
function pdoSelect($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    $returnval = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $returnval;
}
function pdoInsert($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

My problem is in my **jQuery**, `data` from `getMessageNew` is **empty**.

What is happening here?

Comment: Either `echo` or `return`. Both makes no sense.

Comment: I have found the problem. I NEED to `json_encode` my php result first before I can process it properly in javascript.

Comment: You don't, but we can't see that part of your code. If your data is sent over to the browser as JSON then you definitely need to encode it as such.

Comment: jquery can directly read php arrays without json?

Comment: Not arrays, no. I thought you were only returning last inserted ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the result from the select query

```
function getMessageNew($insertid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT message_body FROM tbl_message WHERE m.id = ?';
    $args = array($insertid);
    // output the result
    echo pdoSelect($sql, $args); 
}

function pdoSelect($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    $returnval = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // return the column value
    return $returnval[0]['message_body '];
}
```